# A Gagliardo--Nirenberg inequality in $H^2(\mathbb R^4)$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

Does the following inequality hold in $H^2(\mathbb R^4)$
$$
\sup_{u \in H^2(\mathbb R^4), u\not\equiv 0} \frac{\|u\|_4^4}{\|\Delta u\|_2^2 \|u\|_2^2} > \frac1{16 \pi^2}?
$$

Comment: I guess you meant the opposite inequality?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: thanks for your comment. Why do you think an opposite inequality? In fact, I try to test the inequality for some special functions but it's false. The inequality is important for me. So I don't hope an opposite inequality holds.

Comment: How did you come up with the constant? Do you have any guess what functions achieve the sup?

Comment: @DeaneYang: This inequality comes from a variational problem $\sup F(u)$ with $u$ in unit ball of $H^2(R^4)$. I want to show $\sup F(u) > A$ with a special value $A$. For each function $u$, define $u_t(x) = t^{1/2} u(t^{1/4} x)$ and $v_t = u_t/\|u_t\|_{H^2}$. Expanding $F(v_t)$ for $t$ near $0$, I get 
$$F(v_t) = A + t\left(16\pi^2 \frac{\|u\|_4^4}{\|u\|_2^2 \|\Delta u\|_2^2} -1\right) + o(t)$$
which leads me to the inequality. I have no idea on the extremal functions. I tried for some special functions $e^{-r^a}, (1+ r^2)^{-a}, (1 -r^2)_+^a$ etc but they do not work.

Comment: @nguyen0610: Whoops, I did not notice the $\sup$. Sorry!

Comment: (1/2) As you mentioned, numerical experiments suggest that such $u$ does not exist. A naive approach is off by 50%, however: by Sobolev inequality and Schwarz inequality, $\|u\|_4^4\leqslant C\|\nabla u\|_2^4=C(\langle\hat{u},|\xi|^2\hat{u}\rangle)^2\leqslant C\|u\|_2^2\|\nabla u\|_2^2$, with constant $C=\tfrac{3}{2} \times \tfrac{1}{16\pi^2}$, see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021782402012667).

Comment: (2/2) Note, however, that the minimiser for the Sobolev inequality: $(1+|x|^2)^{-1/2}$ is quite different from minimisers for the Schwarz inequality (Fourier transforms concentrated near a sphere). A natural approach would be to mimic the proof of the Sobolev/Gagliardo–Nirenberg inequalities with optimal constants, replacing the gradient by the Laplacian. This likely leads to nonlinear equations involving bilaplacian, but I did not attempt to write down the formulae.